# Page goes blank when switching to different option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have issue with following code where i want to change from newest to oldest of dropdown.

Initially it shows newest to oldest data but when i select oldest to newest then page goes blank and **Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop shows up.**

My code is like this:

```
import { loadable, Global, css, connect, styled, decode } from "frontity";
import React, {Component} from "react";
const InfiniteListTaxNormal = loadable(() => import('./list-tax-infinite-normal'));
const InfiniteListTaxReverse = loadable(() => import('./list-tax-infinite-reverse'));

const options = [
    {
        label: "newest to oldest",
        value: "newest",
    },
    {
        label: "oldest to newest",
        value: "oldest",
    },
];

let orderState = 0;

class TaxInfiniteList extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            orderDefault: "newest",
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ orderDefault: event.target.value });

        if(event.target.value == "oldest") {
            orderState = 1;
        } else {
            orderState = 0;
        }
    }

render() {

  return (
    <div>

        <Global styles={sortTaxStyles} />
        <div className="SortContainer">
            <div className="SortLabel">
                <h3>Sorted by</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="SortSelect">
                <select value={this.state.orderDefault} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                  {options.map((option) => (
                    <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
                  ))}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        { orderState == 1 ?
            <div>
                <InfiniteListTaxReverse />
            </div>
        :
            <div>
                <InfiniteListTaxNormal />
            </div>
        }


    </div>
  );
}
};

export default TaxInfiniteList;
```

I can see the issue is in setState().

```
this.setState({ orderDefault: event.target.value });
```

## list-tax-infinite-normal

```
const InfiniteListTaxNormal = ({ state, link }) => {

    // Important
    const data = state.source.get(state.router.link);

    const {
        pages,
        isFetching,
        isError,
        isLimit,
        fetchNext
    } = useArchiveInfiniteScroll({ limit: 0 });



return (
    <Container>
        {pages.map(({ Wrapper, key, link, isLast }) => (
            <Wrapper key={key}>
              <AllTax link={link}/>
            </Wrapper>
          ))}
          <ButtonContainer>
            {isFetching && <Loading />}
            {isLimit && <Button onClick={fetchNext}>Load Next Page</Button>}
            {isError && (
              <Button onClick={fetchNext}>Something failed - Retry</Button>
            )}
          </ButtonContainer>
    </Container>

  );
};

export default connect(InfiniteListTaxNormal);
```

## list-tax-infinite-reverse

```
const InfiniteListTaxReverse = ({ state, link }) => {

    // Important
    const data = state.source.get(state.router.link);

    const {
        pages,
        isFetching,
        isError,
        isLimit,
        fetchNext
    } = useArchiveInfiniteScroll({ limit: 0 });

return (

    <Container>
        {pages.map(({ Wrapper, key, link, isLast }) => (
            <Wrapper key={key}>
              <AllTaxReverse link={link}/>
            </Wrapper>
          )).slice().reverse()}
          <ButtonContainer>
            {isFetching && <Loading />}
            {isLimit && <Button onClick={fetchNext}>Load Next Page</Button>}
            {isError && (
              <Button onClick={fetchNext}>Something failed - Retry</Button>
            )}
          </ButtonContainer>
    </Container>

  );
};

export default connect(InfiniteListTaxReverse);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your `InfiniteListTaxReverse` and `InfiniteListTaxNormal` component code?

Comment: This usually happens when something in the render function triggers a setState somewhere, so I agree with the comment above that it could be useful to search the problem inside your InfiniteListTaxReverse and InfiniteListNormal components.

Comment: @KevinYobeth, Please see the updated code.

Comment: @Peterrabbit, please see the updated code.

Comment: complete code is here: https://github.com/zakirsajib/Nirvana-Frontity/blob/main/packages/mars-theme/src/components/list/list-tax-infinite.js

Comment: @ZakirSajib I didn't notice the first time, but something is odd in you handlechange: why do you use that external state `orderState` for your render instead of the real component state ? I don't know if the problem is there but this sure can lead to weird behavior in the component life.

Comment: Also, your two components listnoram and listreverse seems almost identical, are you sure you couldn't just make one component and passing it a prop like "reverse" or not "normal" ? I think it could be cleaner.